# Spring Boot - Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25, response: 421

Tags: spring, spring-boot, email, smtp

I'm using Gmail SMTP host to send mails with spring boot and JavaMail Sender:

my Mail properties:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = XXX@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = XXX

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

Getting error:

```
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.9business.fr, port: 25, response: 421] with root cause
```

even if I'm using port 465 why is he pointing to port 25?

Comment: Add `spring.mail.port=465` to change the port. If that doesn't work, add the error you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found what going wrong, I should use both one of them is the port of my server and the other the one of gmail server :

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 25
mail.smtp.port= 465
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Spring Boot, but generally you should [never need to set the socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  See also the [general JavaMail instructions for using Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you got those properties. The more common Spring Boot properties to configure can be found here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

So you should probably be using `spring.mail.port`. The properties available in the `spring.mail` namespace are:

```
host
port
username
password
defaultEncoding (default: "UTF-8")
```

However, if you are creating your own `JavaMailSender`, the property to set the SMTP port is `mail.smtp.port`. I set up the `JavaMailSender` as a bean like so:

```
@Value(value = "${mail.smtp.host}")
private String smtpHost;

@Value(value = "${mail.smtp.port}")
private String smtpPort;

@Bean
public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    p.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
    sender.setJavaMailProperties(p);

    return sender;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to add the property spring.mail.port = 587 to my file properties,
and now it's pointing at the right port but still geting the same error but with the right port

Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;

Comment: @Steve Spring Boot has support for automatically configuring the `JavaMailSenderImpl` by just specifying the properties in `application.properties`. See the [mail](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-email) section of the reference guide and the [properties section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: That's why I mentioned it, but I have added the full list from the mail config class for clarity. I have got used to creating the sender myself, because I need to disable authentication to connect to MS Exchange in my current environment. For some reason the Spring Boot automagic mail sender doesn't seem to support setting the `mail.smtp.auth` property.

Answer (score 3):

disabled **`mail.smtp.starttls.required`** to **`false`** in your properties file.

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false
```

Comment: Thanks as I have added "spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable" and it works fine for me. By the way, I can't find this properties in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html.
Any idea ?

Comment: spring.mail.properties is a prefix that was added in spring-boot-autoconfigure, however "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" is original properties name in Java mail API.

Comment: Chill.. Thanks @Ajay for the info.

Comment: And for your convenience, here you can see "mail.smtp.*" java properties: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username = xxxxxx
spring.mail.password = xxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
```

Make sure google allow less secure app:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
turn it on

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot.
spring:
mail:
host: smtp.gmail.com
port: 587
username: your-email
password: 'your app-password'
properties:
mail:
transport:
protocol: smtp
smtp:
auth: true
starttls:
enable: true