# Sending email from Spring Boot application using Gmail

Tags: java, email, spring-boot, smtp, gmail

I have studied the following question  and answers:
[Spring Boot - Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25, response: 421](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064904/spring-boot-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-25-response)

I want to do the same thing - send email from a Spring Boot application using the Gmail servers.

My config is this:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = ***@otherdomain
spring.mail.password = ***
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
```

This has been copied from the other question, only the username and password have been changed for my needs. The only different thing about my scienario as that the domain of the email address is not gmail.com.

My Email Client class is:

```
@Service
public class MailClient {

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender mailSender;

  public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
    MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
        messageHelper.setFrom("me@otherdomain.org.uk");
        messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
        messageHelper.setSubject("Sample mail subject");
        messageHelper.setText(message);
    };
    mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
  }
}
```

My exception is:

```
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g78sm6788965wrd.11 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Do you mean with other domain, that you use a Google for work account with a custom domain? Or is that domain totally unrelated to any Google accounts?

Comment: It is my own domain whose MX records point to Gmail.

Comment: Have you tried to specify `spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=465`? socketFactory.port only sets your local port, not the one which should be used at the SMTP server.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without duplicating your config (with the exception of `From Email` in this case but this will depend on your `SMTP` provider):

**Dependency**

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=from.email@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=*******
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

**EmailService**

```
@Component
public class EmailService {

    private final JavaMailSender sender;

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(JavaMailSender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String body) {
        MimeMessagePreparator message = newMessage -> {
            newMessage.setRecipient(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(emailTo)
            );
            newMessage.setFrom("from.email@gmail.com");
            newMessage.setSubject(subject);
            newMessage.setText(body);
        };

        this.sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question in case anyone else finds it useful:

The required set of properties is this:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=****
spring.mail.password=****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

You also need to provide the JavaMailSender yourself and set additional properties:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername("***");
    mailSender.setPassword("***");

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}
```

Not sure why I needed to repeat the config, but that worked for me. Reference: [baeldung.com](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email)

Answer (score 1):

you used **smtp.gmail.com** so the email should be **gmail**

**EDIT :** 
in my application in **spring mvc** i do like this : 
service:

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;


    /**
         * This method will send compose and send the message
         * */
        public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body)
        {
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            mailSender.send(message);
        }
```

in the controller i used my service

```
applicationMailer.sendMail("*******@gmail.com", "Message from "+ userName , mailModel.getBody());
```

and for **configuration** :

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>  <!--   ou 25 -->
        <property name="username" value="*****@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="******"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I tried using a different gmail account where the email address is ...@gmail.com. Same result.

Comment: try with port = 25 ,instead of 465