# Spring mail disable TLS

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use localhost as the mail server but getting "454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem" error.

How can I disable TLS for mail?

I'm using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mail.smtp.starttls.enable` and `mail.smtp.starttls.required` are two properties defined in JavaMail. However, in order to use them in a Spring application, we need to add them to application properties using the "additional properties" method in Spring. Relevant excerpt from [Spring Boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

```
spring.mail.properties.*= # Additional JavaMail session properties.
```

Hence, in short, we need to add the following to our `application.properties` file to use mail without TLS in Spring:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39716248/3395831)

Comment: FWIW adding only `.enable` worked for me (Boot 1.5.5 though); didn't need to add `.required` entry

Comment: Usefull reference for properties: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#:~:text=is%20NOT%20supported.-,Properties,-The%20SMTP%20protocol